# Big Data with cURL

Tags: php, perl, bash, curl, vps

I own VPS server, I want to do something with my server which I have Big data about 15K usernames.

What I need, to send all usernames as cURL request with: website.com/getaccount.php?username= every minute.

so what is the solution for that case .. I don't want to make it with Cron because it will take 15K jobs and that is very bad.

in which language could I optimize 15K users ? bash ? perl ? php ? and if I can make it separate files and each file content 5K users.

Please give me a solution, thanks alot ..

Comment: 15k usernames is not "Big Data" by any sensible measure. It's tiny data.

Comment: @StephenD ok an advice ?

Comment: @Mat an advice my dear ? what could I do for do all curl requests without any delay

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you most likely want to distribute this big job by using a job server such as [Gearman](http://gearman.org/)

**Gearman** is extremely flexible, and you can use it to batch process a large number of jobs in parallel very quickly.

When it comes to what language you should use...I would use whatever you're comfortable in. I have processed large jobs ( *much larger than the one you described* ) using **bash** + **php** in the past. Php has some very good wrapper libraries that you can use to get things started pretty quickly.

Hope this helps you to go in the correct direction.

Suggested links:

[Gearman PHP Extension - Quick Start](http://gearman.org/gearman_php_extension)

[PHP daemon for managing gearman workers](https://github.com/brianlmoon/GearmanManager/)

[Basic Gearman client and worker, submitting tasks](http://php.net/manual/en/gearman.examples-reverse-task.php)

Answer (score 0):

Does all usernames change from minute to minute? If no, then it's useless to send them all. Only send differencies (deltas) like 'deleting user1' or 'adding user2' or 'renaming user1 to user2'

Also, If I understand your example correctly, you want to make a cURL request for each username, which means 15K request every minute. For me that look like a waste of resources similar to a dDos attack. I hope that is not what you want to acheive on your own server.

Maybe try to reduce your data amount to only relevant data and batch all that data in a single cUrl request!

15K isn't that big, but you need to handle it correctly!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to create a file in which each line is a username. Once you have your file, you can use the tool [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/) to sync it into whatever system you want. From that system, you can fetch that file to update all that please you. 15K is not such a big deal actually, the problem is more about the delay. Each minute is quite fast. You can produce your file from any language that can connect to your datasource, rsync can be trigger from a cron job every minute without any problem.

The use of cURL here could be for a particular username (if exist, if password match, etc.), but here the only reason I can see to your request is for backup, and as I said a minute is very fast for that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want to send all your users data to a distant php script through cURL is it right ? 
if it's the case your can use Python to write a little script with a Sleep function thats fires every 1mn

**Syntax :**

import time
time.sleep(secs)